# How to transmit initial payload to the client in ActionCable subscribed callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, actioncable

I have Ruby on Rails application which is using ActionCable for real-time client communication. I have `ScoreChannel` which is responsible for streaming user score updates:

```
class ScoreChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def self.broadcast_name(user:)
    "score_#{user.guid}"
  end

  def broadcast_name
    self.class.broadcast_name(user: current_user)
  end

  def subscribed
    stream_from(broadcast_name)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast(broadcast_name, Cable::V1::ScoreSerializer.new(current_user).as_json)
  end
end
```

I am trying to send user's current score right after a user subscribes to the channel (see `ScoreChannel#subscribed` method). Unfortunately, due to asynchronous nature of ActionCable, score broadcast goes before user subscribes to the `ScoreChannel`. Therefore user does not receive the initial score payload (because he is not subscribed to this channel yet). This is redis monitor timeline:

```
1472430005.884742 [1 172.18.0.6:50242] "subscribe" "action_cable/Z2lkOi8vYXBwLWVuZ2luZS9Vc2VyLzE"
1472430010.988077 [1 172.18.0.6:50244] "publish" "score_cc112e3fdfb5411a965a31f9468abf98" "{\"score\":17,\"rank\":1}"
1472430010.988773 [1 172.18.0.6:50242] "subscribe" "score_cc112e3fdfb5411a965a31f9468abf98"
```

What is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `ActionCable.server.broadcast` to broadcast to the existing subscribers, try using the `transmit`-method, like this:

```
transmit(Cable::V1::ScoreSerializer.new(current_user).as_json)
```

This only sends the status to the current subscriber being handled, but I figured this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

use `transmit` inside a channel class/instance, ref `ActionCable::Channel::Base#transmit`

use `broadcast` outside channel class, ref `ActionCable::Server#broadcast`